# Vue.js lifecycle events and where to start loading store properties (Vue.observable)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, observable, vue-router

I'm using Vue.observable() to manage state and need to wait for two store properties to be populated before most views are loaded by vue-router.

Tried putting the loading in the beforeCreate, created and mounted lifecycle events in App.vue since it's the root of my web app:

```
<template lang='pug'>
#app
  AppHeader
  router-view
  AppFooter
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import AppHeader from '@/components/AppHeader.vue'; // @ is an alias to /src
import AppFooter from '@/components/AppFooter.vue';
import { mutations } from '@/store';

@Component({
  components: {
    AppHeader, AppFooter
  }
})
export default class App extends Vue {
  private async beforeCreate(): Promise<[void, void]> {
    return await Promise.all([ mutations.clientSet(), mutations.productsSet()]);
  }
}
</script>
```

But the vue-router loads the other views that depend on these state properties before the promises have a chance to resolve. All of my views are dependent on the properties being populated so moving `return await Promise.all([ mutations.clientSet(), mutations.productsSet()]);` to their lifecycle event handlers isn't very efficient.

Is there a better place to run this code so it's guaranteed to finish before the vue-router loads the views?

Answer (score 0):

I modified my store for each of the two properties to change them to promises (instead of the result). Anywhere I needed the values in views, I now await the values.

This allows the UI to load quickly and only wait where needed.